# Recursion in Python: Max Depth Exceeded

Tags: python, recursion

I am confused how to do recursion in python, when to return and when to update a global variable.

Consider this question: https://leetcode.com/problems/nested-list-weight-sum-ii/

> Given a nested list of integers, return the sum of all integers in the
>   list weighted by their depth, where the leaf level integers have
>   weight 1, and the root level integers have the largest weight.

```
Input: [[1,1],2,[1,1]]
```

Here is my solution:

```
class Solution:

    def depthSumInverse(self, nestedList: List[NestedInteger]) -> int:

        md = 0

        def maxdepth(nestedList, m):

            for i in nestedList:

                 if i.isInteger() == False:
                     md = max (m + 1, md)
                     maxdepth(nestedList, m+1)

            return md


        def depthSum(nestedList, maxdepth):

            s = 0

            for i in nestedList:
                t = i.isInteger()
                if t:
                    s += i.getInteger() * maxdepth
                else:
                    s += depthSum(i.getList(), maxdepth-1)

            return s

        m = maxdepth(nestedList, 1)

        return depthSum(nestedList, m)
```

Recursion Error: Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded.

How to do recursion while updating md here?

Comment: You exceeded maximum recursion depth. That means you successfully _did_ recursion.

Comment: @uprego i did it incorrectly then, doesnt matter.. :) have to get the correct way

Comment: Use a debugger and run in steps, or create some temporary standard output prints, or some permanent trace log level calls.

Comment: That'll help you find an error, a missing base case, whatever the problem is.

Comment: The answer depends on the range of input that LeetCode will use to test your method.  The link you provided above requires a login and so doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, I would say that in the last line of this part

```
    def maxdepth(nestedList, m):

        for i in nestedList:

             if i.isInteger() == False:
                 md = max (m + 1, md)
                 maxdepth(nestedList, m+1)
```

you probably want to be doing

```
                 maxdepth(i, m+1)
```

instead, or you'll just be continually calling `maxDepth` on the original input list without actually traversing the hierarchy of nested lists.